# Id query VS Key query GAE

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm asking a question during my development so if somone help it will be good:
What the difference between using the key of an entitie to get it from the datastore or using the ID (in string format)?
Is the key lower cost of operation in the datastore than ID?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "getbykey" queries are indeed free, so it's better than looking up by ID cost-wise.

Comment: So what the difference between query by id or query to a simple indexed field?